# Differences between "very" and "very much" as adjective modifiers

Tags: adjectives, word-usage, writing, speech, modifiers

The following examples are clearly wrong:

> × I am very much tired
>   × She is very much clever

But the following sounds fine (at least according to [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/very_1)):

> I am very much afraid that ...
>   I am very much aware of ...

Worse, the following sounds awkward to me:

> × I am very aware of ...

I wonder some sound ok while the others do not. Does it have to do with the type of adjectives being used? Or is there a subtle nuance between "very" and "very much"? Is "very much" the same as "extremely" (I would guess not, at least in the "afraid" example)? When should/can one use "very much", as opposed to "very"? Are there differences between spoken and written uses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say "very much" isn't used with adjectives of characteristics/qualities that tend to be inherent or permanent (She's very intelligent.)

And we tend to use very much with other adjectives, especially if they go with a preposition. (I'm very much aware OF the fact that...)

Good question. I can imagine my students asking me this in the near future.

Comment: Good question indeed. And I think the point about 'adjectival complements' (afraid that/of ...; aware of ...; ready for the encounter is relevant, though by no means a firm rule (very wrong of him to come; very eager for the holidays to come). The actual adjective seems to have a say in the matter, alongside other factors. I think this will need a doctoral thesis as an answer (and I'd bet even that wouldn't come up with firm rules).

Answer (score 0):

Collins COBUILD English Usage:

**Much** and **very much** are used **in front of comparatives**, but are **not usually used in front of other adjectives**. However, you can use them **in front of -ed words**. *▲ Education is a much debated subject. ▲ She was very much attached to her husband.*

You can use **very much** in front of **afraid, alike, alive, and awake.** *▲ I am very much afraid that she will end by marrying her cousin. ▲ Dolly and Molly were very much alike. ▲ The animal was not dead but very much alive. ▲ The children were very much awake.*