# Grammatical problem about very and much

Tags: adverbs

I was very exhausted in the evening.

She is very tired after a day's work.

In the first sentence very can be replaced by much, but in the second sentence this is not the case. I need to ask why.[image]

I have uploaded a picture for the concerned problem. Please review for the same.

Comment: Today, we don't say *was very exhausted* ***or*** *was much exhausted*. We say *was completely exhausted* (or *totally exhausted*, etc.).  [See Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+very+exhausted%2Cwas+much+exhausted%2Cwas+very+much+exhausted%2Cwas+completely+exhausted&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=6&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwas%20very%20exhausted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20much%20exhausted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20very%20much%20exhausted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20completely%20exhausted%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: What do you mean exactly? _Very_ is not replaced by _much_ in either sentence as far as I can tell, nor would it normally be in current English.

Comment: @Janus: the OP is presumably being taught 19th century English, not 21st century English. [See Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+very+exhausted%2Cwas+much+exhausted%2Cwas+completely+exhausted&year_start=1800&year_end=2020&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwas%20very%20exhausted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20much%20exhausted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20completely%20exhausted%3B%2Cc0). Or possibly Indian English, which retains some aspects of 19th century English that are no longer correct in the U.S. and the U.K.

Comment: @PeterShor That is a possibility, but I really have no idea. The question states that _very_ is replaced by _much_ in one of the sentences given, but it isn’t. Who knows what the context may be?

Comment: We must use 'much(adverb)' in place of 'very' in case of past participle form of verb(also with comparative degree) . Similarly 'very' modifies present participle used as adjective, adverbs and positive degree adjective.

Comment: @PeterShor Who are "we"?

Comment: OP has some gyaan for the erudite here.

Comment: Belongs on [ell.se] -- possibly already answered there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confusion about "very" and "very much"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/207059/confusion-about-very-and-very-much)

Answer (score 1):

In the first sentence, 'very' isn't replaced by much.

***I was much exhausted in the evening*** doesn't make sense.  It would still be:  ***I was very exhausted in the evening***.

We cannot use very with comparative adjectives. Instead, we use much, far, very much, a lot, lots, rather, a little, a bit etc.

In the same way, we cannot use much with positive adjectives. We cannot, for example, say He is much intelligent. Instead, we say: He is very intelligent.

Here's how to use very and much:

https://www.englishpractice.com/improve/correct-use-of-much-and-very/

Comment: Making sense in your way doesn't mean sentence is wrong. Much can be place instead of very with certain conditions.

Comment: It doesn't here.  _I was much exhausted in the evening_ is never going to make sense.  Thought it is true in some cases you can use 'very much'.

Answer (score -1):

'Exhausted' means 'very tired'. 
According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:
exhausted 
: completely or almost completely depleted of resources or contents.
So 'exhausted' can not be modified by 'very' but we can say: 'absolutely (or quite) exhausted'.

Comment: Of course _exhausted_ can be modified by _very_. It can’t be modified by _much_ in normal, current English, though.